# PHP echo working with the browser, not with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm writing a web interface for an application. Since the elaboration time for the application can be pretty long, when it starts the user is shown a loading page and then an AJAX call loads the output to the page. If I browse the PHP function with my browser I get the correct response (a JSON), but when the AJAX call is executed jQuery gets an error 500 (I tried with the same parameters).

This is the JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: my_url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result){
          if (result.status == "COMPLETED") {
            window.alert("RETURNED");
            $("hocrDisplay").attr("src", result.html);
            $("hocrDownload").attr("href", resul.path);
            $("#loaderImage").hide();
            $("#hocrDisplay").show();
            $("#hocrDownload").show();
            window.alert("The file will be deleted in 10 minutes");
           }else{
             setTimeout(getStatus(requestid,filename), 3000);
          }
      },
      error: function (response) {
        alert("There was an error processing the document");
        $("#loaderImage").hide();

  }
  });
```

And this is the code around the PHP echo:

```
echo json_encode('{"status" : "COMPLETED", "html" : "' . $htmlname . '", "path" : "' . $tarpath . '"}');
ob_flush();
sleep(600);
unlink($tarpath);
unlink($htmlname);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are encoding the `string` which already encoded, its better to use an `array` than use `json_encode` function for encoding.

You can try like that:

```
// create an array for your values
$yourArr = array(
            'status'=>'COMPLETED',
            'html'=>$htmlname,
            'path'=>$tarpath);

// encode the array in json format
echo json_encode($yourArr);
```

**json_encode will return this:**

```
{"status":"COMPLETED","html":"test","path":"test2"}
```

Now, you can use it in `ajax` success as you are already doing.

Comment: Accepted answer is a copy of my answer? OMG!

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: your code was not correct .... here is the correct code... http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34740257/revisions

Comment: Your solution is a copy of my answer, you only change the typo mistake that can be in a comment. But ok, you win.

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong:

```
echo json_encode('{"status" : "COMPLETED", "html" : "' . $htmlname . '", "path" : "' . $tarpath . '"}');
```

You should make an array and then encode it in JSON like this:

```
$array = array("status"=>"COMPLETED",
               "html"=>$htmlname,
               "path"=>$tarpath);
echo json_encode($array);
```

This encodes you the correct jSON. The 500 error is in server, so that line it that produces the error.

Good luck,

Comment: It doesn't throw any error when I call the php directly from the broswer, which is at least strange, but I will try.

Comment: i have fixed your code.. else your code is fine... will work.. earned my vote.

Comment: Thank you, my mistake with the `:` instead of `=>`